# For and While Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I have a program that runs simultaneously and I have this problem where I want to stop the thread but the for loop/while loop doesn't get cancelled once I once I click enter

If I take the `for` loop out of the `while` loop, the program actually responds to the enter and shuts down.

```
class MyNumber extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean processing = true;

    public void run() {
        while (processing) {
            // Once I take this for loop out(put // beside it like right now), the enter key to stop the program then does work.
            //for(int i = 1; i<27; i++){
             System.out.println("Letter " + "i");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // }
        }
    }

    public void permSleep() {
        processing = false;
    }
}

public class LetterNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNumber num1 = new MyNumber();
        num1.start();

        System.out.println("Hit enter to stop the Numbers!");
        Scanner shutter1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        shutter1.nextLine();

        num1.permSleep();
    }
}
```

Why does the `for` loop cause the program to *not* shutdown?

Comment: Btw, it wasn't supposed to say while(processing == true), but just while(processing). Also, would the while loop not break once entered something in the console due to be calling the permSleep method which makes the variable processing == false?

Comment: That's going to print "Letter i" once a second, indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you're asking.  However, if you're expecting that the `while` and `for` loops will both terminate as soon as `processing` is set to `true`, that isn't what happens.  A `while` will execute the statement in the body (i.e. the `for` loop), **then** it will test the condition (`processing == true`), then if it's true, it executes the statement again, and **then** tests the condition again.  It doesn't test it while the `for` loop is executing.  It doesn't "notice" when the `processing` variable is set.  So when `processing` is set to `true`, the `for` loop will keep going until it's done, which could be another 26 seconds.

To fix this simply, add

```
if (!processing)
    break;
```

inside the `for` loop.  Now the `processing` flag will be tested each time through the `for` loop.  (If it were me, I'd put a "label" on the `while` loop and use that to `break` out of both loops.)  Another way to fix it:

```
for(int i = 1; i<27 && processing; i++){
```

which means the `for` loop will continue only as long as `processing` is `true`.

**Note:** These solutions will still not test `processing` while the `sleep(1000)` is going on.  So the program could still pause up to 1 second before it terminates.  If you really want a solution that will terminate the `sleep`, you'll have use `interrupt` or some other concurrency feature.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (!processing)`?

Comment: Really explained it thoroughly and it fixed the problem. Thanks a bunch @HotLicks I realized that too and just put (processing == false)

Comment: @fastcodejava - The point is to insert the above sequence inside the inner `for` loop, so that it gets checked on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Your `for` loop takes about `27` seconds to finish. It should come out of that after the `for` loop has finished.

Comment: Yeah the for loop works fine, it's just that once I hit enter and enter it into the console, the thread doesn't stop like it should. I tried taking out the for loop and notice that now the thread does stop on the entering of 'enter'.

Comment: Did you wait a while?